# Error throwing Objective-C function not translated to Swift by XCode 6.4

Tags: objective-c, swift, error-handling, try-catch, throw

I modified a function in objective C to throw errors. I then want to catch these errors in Swift. I implemented the Bridging function, and it looks that everything is in order.  I am getting the error:

> Consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ';'

just right after the command:

```
try rfduino.send(data)
```

If I don't use `try`, it starts asking me for a second parameter. The function worked before I implemented this error handling. I am using XCode 6.4.

I also read in http://blog.benjamin-encz.de/swift-error-handling-and-objective-c-interop-in-depth/ 
that XCode only translate the function to a Swift-like error throwing function when the function returns a BOOL or an ObjectiveC type. I also tried that.

What can it be?

My .h file looks like:

```
- (BOOL)send:(NSData *)data
       error:(NSError**) errorPtr;
```

in .m file:

```
- (BOOL)send:(NSData *)data
       error:(NSError**)errorPtr
{
    if (! loadedService) {

        if (errorPtr) {
            *errorPtr = [NSError errorWithDomain:NSCocoaErrorDomain
                                            code:NSFileNoSuchFileError
                                        userInfo:@{NSLocalizedDescriptionKey:  NSLocalizedString(@"No Device Connected.", nil),
                                                   NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey: NSLocalizedString(@"The connection is not loaded.", nil),
                                                   NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestionErrorKey: NSLocalizedString(@"Try disconnecting and connecting again", nil)
                                                   }];
        } else {
            @throw [NSException exceptionWithName:@"sendDataNoDevice" reason:@"please wait for ready callback" userInfo:nil];
        }
        return(NO);
    }

    if ([data length] > max_data) {
        if (errorPtr) {
            *errorPtr = [NSError errorWithDomain:NSCocoaErrorDomain
                                            code:NSFileNoSuchFileError
                                        userInfo:@{NSLocalizedDescriptionKey:  NSLocalizedString(@"No Device Connected.", nil),
                                                   NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey: NSLocalizedString(@"The connection is not loaded.", nil),
                                                   NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestionErrorKey: NSLocalizedString(@"Try disconnecting and connecting again", nil)
                                                   }];
        } else {
            @throw [NSException exceptionWithName:@"sendDataTooLarge" reason:@"max data size exceeded" userInfo:nil];
        }
        return(NO);
    }

    [peripheral writeValue:data forCharacteristic:send_characteristic type:CBCharacteristicWriteWithoutResponse];
    return(YES);
}
```

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to update Xcode.

`Consecutive statements...` usually appears when Xcode doesn't understand the syntax: indeed `do try catch` is only available in Xcode 7+ with Swift 2.